# How to create cutom tag inside UniGrid GridColumns between two td?

Tags: c#, kentico

I am using Kentico 8.2 and I have UniGrid with following code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TestCode.ascx.cs" 
    Inherits="TestCode" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/CMSAdminControls/UI/UniGrid/UniGrid.ascx" TagName="UniGrid" TagPrefix="cms" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ug" Namespace="CMS.UIControls.UniGridConfig" Assembly="CMS.UIControls, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=834b12a258f213f9" %>

<cms:UniGrid runat="server" ID="TEST">

<GridColumns>

<ug:Column runat="server"
            Source="mysource1"/>

<ug:Column runat="server"
            Source="mysource2"/>

</GridColumns>
</cms:UniGrid>
```

UniGrid generated one `tr` for each item with two `<td>`. Can I create custom tag which will have this two td's ?

Comment: What do you mean by a custom tag? What are you trying to achieve? Sample html output would help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code, dynamically add the `Column` to the `GridColumns` collection.

Each `Column` is a single table cell so if you want to have a single control do this you'd need to create it based on the `UniGridConfig.Column` object